# register_setting registered with incorrect data type

Tags: plugin-development

I tried to register a `boolean` setting for my plugin using:

```php
register_setting( 'my_plugin_settings', 'prefix_some_checkbox', array('type' => 'boolean') );
```

However, after checking the database, `prefix_some_checkbox`'s `option_value` is stored as `longtext`. What am I doing wrong here?
Also `var_dump(get_option('prefix_some_checkbox'))` says the value is a string. This is how I save my checkbox value:

```
<?php $option_name = get_option( 'prefix_some_checkbox' ); ?>
<input name="prefix_some_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked(1, $option_name); ?> />
```

Comment: Check the [docs page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) and have a read of the user contrib notes.

Comment: `option_value` will always be `longtext`. It's a database column, the type can't change for each row.

Comment: Thank you! both comments are the answers I was looking for